# How to find the current sun angle from Earth's rotation?

Tags: javascript, date, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to replicate the sun's light on the Earth on a WebGL globe, but I'm struggling to find "where" the sun currently is. Ideally I'd need an angle mapped from 0 to 1 to pass to my vertex shader.

The code below is working but the issue is to find what the `dayTime` value would be (I suppose based on `new Date()`?). Would that imply an API or is it data that can be calculated?

```js
// dayTime = 0 - 24h ----> 0 - 1

const d = degToRad(360 / dayTime)
const sunPos = new Vec3(
    Math.cos(d),
    Math.sin(d) * Math.sin(0),
    Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(0)
)

this.program.uniforms.sunPosition.value = sunPos
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Converting a range from 0-24 to a range of 0-1?

Comment: @caTS I'm mostly struggling to find the value of `dayTime`, mapping it from 0-24 to 0-1 would be easy

Comment: Given a Date object, you can convert it to GMT timezone with `new Date(myDate.toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZone: "GMT" }))`, then call `getHours` to get the hours from 0-24.

Comment: @caTS That would give me the current time from a specific timezone, but would that match where the sun _is_ from the Earth? I'm just trying to find/follow the true position of the sun based on the current time. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Well... time is relative to where you are on Earth... so you could just use `new Date().getHours()`...

Comment: @caTS that makes total sense, however the goal here is to represent where the sun is shining on the Earth at the time we visit the site, wherever we are

Comment: Where is the sun shining on the earth at the time I visit the site?  I guess the time zone that's closest to noon.

Comment: @James very clever! Did not think of that. How could we find this closest timezone to noon?

Comment: *dayTime* can't be a value from 0 to 1 otherwise `360 / dayTime` will result in division by zero and have a **minimum** value of 360. A rough approximation of where the sun is is to use the UTC hour to get the longitude of where it's noon, e.g. `360 * utcHour/24`. But you need radians for *Math.sin* etc. so `2 * Math.PI * utcHour/24`. Anyway, it seems this question is nothing to do with ECMAScript *per se*.

Comment: BTW, `Math.sin(0)` and `Math.cos(0)` are constants. Likely the character in brackets is not zero but the greek letter theta (θ), which represents latitude to give the declination of the sun (elevation north or south of the observer).